# iOS: Custom button (subclass of UIButton) - cannot change border properties

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have custom button consisting of green background, white text and no border. I created class ThemedButton which inherist from UIButton. I then change button properties in awakeFromNib method.

For some reason changing background and title colors work fine, but manipulating border properties (or even rounded corners) does not. My button has green background with white text but also ugly blue border.

My implementation is below.

EDIT: Sorry for my confusing properties. I also tried to set border color to the same as background to get rid of it this way.

```
import UIKit

class ThemedButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Works
        setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        layer.backgroundColor = GREEN_COLOR.cgColor

        // Does not work
        layer.borderWidth = 0
        layer.borderColor = GREEN_COLOR.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 5

    }

}
```

Comment: your borderWidth is 0

Comment: There is no need to subclass UIButton to have all of it. Do you have any other reasons ro subclassing?

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov I need this button in at least two places so I felt this to be cleaner solution than setting properties to each buttons.

Comment: @Filip, it's definitely not. By doing it you will pollute your codebase with useless classes very soon.

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov what would be better solution then? As far as I know I cannot set border in Xcode designer..

Comment: It is borderless by default.

Comment: Perhaps you have accessibility feature "buttons shapes" enabled?

Comment: PS: You can set layer's cornerRadius via "User Defined runtime attributes", or expose it by adding `IBInspectable` extension for UIView/UIControl/UIButton

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov just checked accessibility and button shapes is disable. What do you mean borderless? When I add UIButton to View it has blue text and also blue outline...

Answer (score 3):

set the width of the border

```
 layer.borderWidth = 5
```

This works

```
class ThemedButto22n: UIButton {

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()


  }

 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    // Works
    setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

    // Does not work
    layer.borderWidth = 5
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.cornerRadius = 5


}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this finally removes border but my title also disappeared. All I have is green rectangle.

Comment: @Filip, my title disappeared as well.  To fix, add a call to super.layoutSubviews() at the END of the above implementation.